# Swiss franc banknotes design

Tags: currency, cash, chf-swiss-franc

Why Swiss Franc banknotes do not have year of issue on the paper? I tried to find such number (year) without success - maybe it is with very small font...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about an issue of personal finance that the OP is facing.

Comment: It is about money tough - so i would suggest to keep it

Comment: @DilipSarwate OK, what is the correct SE subforum? BTW, if you keep some amount in cash (CHF), is this "personal finance" or not? It is savings in foreign currency and I think belongs to personal finance.

Comment: Questions about currency are inherently fundamental to personal finance. This question is on-topic.

Comment: @i486 there isn't automatically a SE site for any question you might want to ask.

Comment: Without taking a position on whether this question is on-topic or not, I suggest using https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to decide, not the name of the site.

Comment: @chepner Ok, the question is related to saving and investing. If you are not Swiss citizen and not seen CHF banknotes, you have to recognize how Swiss francs look - there are 8 different series and most of them are not valid now. The year of issue is the most simple way to decide whether this banknote is new and probably valid or its value is only numismatic.

Comment: The year won't tell you anything about the bill being valid; any fake could also show a current year. That sounds more like an argument pulled from where the sun doesn't shine.

Comment: @Aganju What "fake"? The question is not how to identify fake banknotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 2 digits of the serialnumber are the printing year. E.g. 00 is 2000, 94 is 1994, 19 is 2019.

Source: SRF

Comment: Thanks. Is there similar information about series of banknote (6-7-8, etc.)?

Comment: Not sure if i understand the question correclty - but you can look up the information how long one series was produced and how long its valid (based on the series). Also the design of the series differs greatly if you need to check which series it belongs to...